# How to hide some of the views of a CoordinatorLayout

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-layout, layout

I have a layout which contains lot of views inside, let's say the hierarchy is :

- CoordinatorLayout

  - NestedScrollView

    - ConstraintLayout

      - ConstraintLayout

        - SomeViews
      - View (separator)
      - ConstraintLayout

        - SomeViews
      - View (separator)
      - etc...
  - include of AppBar
  - MyCustomProgressBar
- close CoordinatorLayout

The thing is that I've created a `Group` with the `constraint_referenced_ids` of the id's that I want to hide (they are inside the hierarchy tree, but when I try to hide them and show another one they are not hide, I still see them.

My idea is, I want this layout be like is it now, but add a ProgressBar that when it is loading it's only visible that ProgressBar, for instance

I do an api call

> Progress Bar visible
> I got response from api
> Hide progress bar
> Make visible Group and fill the values inside

I've tried to add them inside the `CoordinatorLayout` as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/myRoot"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

   <ConstraintLayout>...</ConstraintLayout>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <MyCustomProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:id="@+id/my_custom_progress_bar"/>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="lot_of_ids"
        android:id="@+id/myGroup"/>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

But I couldn't make it work, what I'm missing?

The idea in general is to be able to keep using that big layout as it was but just add some views for instance a `ProgressBar` and also an `EmptyCustomView` to show them without overlapping the information, just showing that exact View, I've done it many times but not in `CoordinatorLayout`, like separating it with "states", when the state is Loading then show *only* the progressBar, when the state is Empty then show the EmptyCustomView and when the state is the Success then show the layout as it is from start but hiding the others.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question perfectly. However, what I infer is that you are trying to hide some views, and it is easy to do so programmatically.

Step 1: Give the view to hide an ID in the XML declaration. Say it's a TextView.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/view_to_hide"
    .../>
```

Step 2: Declare the View in your Java file.

```
TextView toHide = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.view_to_hide);
```

Step 3: Wherever you need to, hide the View by calling the `setVisibility` method on it.

```
toHide.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //for visible
toHide.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); //for invisible
```

There are other values such as `View.GONE`; however, I find `VISIBLE` and `INVISIBLE` sufficient for all my purposes.

Also note that this method works for literally anything that extends the `View` class (e.g., this can be called on even `LinearLayout`s and such). On the setting `View.INVISIBLE`, the View cannot gain focus and cannot be clicked. I hope this answer helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at View.setVisibility(View.GONE / View.VISIBLE / View.INVISIBLE).

```
<ConstraintLayout
 android:visibility="gone">
 ...
</ConstraintLayout>
```